Blink.cmp unable to load config after new LazyVim update. Expected table but got boolean for treesitter
Whenever I Load up Neovim I get the following error:
Failed to run config for blink.cmp

...share/nvim/lazy/blink.cmp/lua/blink/cmp/config/utils.lua:10: completion.menu.draw.treesitter: expected table, got boolean

stacktrace:
/blink.cmp/lua/blink/cmp/config/utils.lua:10 in validate
/blink.cmp/lua/blink/cmp/config/completion/menu.lua:163 in validate
/blink.cmp/lua/blink/cmp/config/completion/init.lua:37 in validate
/blink.cmp/lua/blink/cmp/config/init.lua:41 in validate
/blink.cmp/lua/blink/cmp/config/init.lua:52 in merge_with
/blink.cmp/lua/blink/cmp/init.lua:18 in setup
/LazyVim/lua/lazyvim/plugins/extras/coding/blink.lua:163 in config
/LazyVim/lua/lazyvim/plugins/lsp/init.lua:181 in config
vim/_editor.lua:0
/neo-tree.nvim/lua/neo-tree/utils/init.lua:741 in open_file
/neo-tree.nvim/lua/neo-tree/sources/common/commands.lua:733 in open
/neo-tree.nvim/lua/neo-tree/sources/common/commands.lua:755 in open_with_cmd
/neo-tree.nvim/lua/neo-tree/sources/common/commands.lua:764 in open
/neo-tree.nvim/lua/neo-tree/sources/filesystem/commands.lua:184

Can't get blink.cmp to work. Seeing this issue after the new LazyVim update which changed the default autocomplete from nvim-cmp to blink.cmp. Any help would be appreciated!
Additional Info: I have no customised config for blink.
Removed the cache from ~/.local/share/nvim and opened nvim again, it installed all the plugins, essentially a refresh.
This is a fresh install and I haven't created any custom config files for it. Any help?

I suggest reporting bugs to plugin maintainers

It looks like the issue you're having was fixed a couple of days ago by Pull Request #5212 in LazyVim (in this commit.
Update your LazyVim to latest again, that should fix the issue for you.
